# Embedded browser with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am writing a web application that will run in kiosk mode on a touch screen. I am currently only targeting it for running on Firefox 3. A few of the use cases I have need to visit external sites. I wish to do so with an embedded browser, which I'm tackling with the help of an `<iframe>`. I need back/forward buttons for the embedded home page.

I've managed to access the history object of the iframe with

```
var w = document.getElementById('embeddedBrowser').contentWindow;
w.history.back();
```

The `history` of the embedded window is the same as that of the parent window. Therefore for a newly loaded `<iframe>`, this call will go back to the previous page of the system.

Is there any way to avoid this or a more correct way of solving this?

Comment: Are you embedding this inside another application?

Comment: I have a web application running on the touch screen, in kiosk mode. The embedded site is simply an iframe inside a page in the web app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is only one history object shared within each tab this seems impossible. The proper way around it would be to test `window.history.current` or `window.history.previous` before calling back. Unfortunately, `window.history.current` is privileged and so not available to unsigned pages.

Here's a rough sketch of a messy workaround:

```
<iframe src="somepage.html" name="myframe"></iframe>
<p><a href="#" id="backBtn">Back</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById('backBtn').onclick = function () {
    if (window.frames['myframe'].location.hash !== '#stopper') {
      window.history.back();
    }
    // ... else hide the button?
    return false; // pop event bubble
  };
  window.frames['myframe'].onload = function () {
    this.location.hash = 'stopper';
  };

</script>
```

Of course, this is assuming that no (#hash) browsing ever goes on in parent window, and so on, but it seems to work for the problem of limiting back movement.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/develop/ajax/). It lets you write your application using all the same tools / languages (ajax, html, etc etc), but since it runs as a desktop app and not in a web browser, you have more control over things, such as embedding browser frames and knowing exactly what they are doing, what URL it's going to, controlling it's history, etc. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149338/adobe-air-book-from-htmljavascript-perspective#149432) for a few pointers on getting started.